# Responsive two column panel layout in priority order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, positioning

I've been working on a way to display panels on a homepage, the page is responsive and would start off with all the panels being 100% wide and stacking and then at a certain breakpoint the panels would split into two columns.

My work in progress is here http://codepen.io/charge-valtech/pen/aIEGf

This works nicely with the panels flowing in priority order from left to right.  However the problem is this page would need to be dynamic, so any of the panels could be "switched off".  So if you got rid of the third panel, because of the way floats work the fourth panel tries to go over to the right, even though float: left has been specified.

Using clearing would keep it to the left, but then there would be a gap where the third panel was...

I hope this makes some sense and was just interested in how other people might approach the problem.  I'm thinking JavaScript might be the way to go but wouldn't really know how to go about detecting if there's white space available.

Cheers

Comment: You thought about using masonry? http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: I did have a little play with masonry before, perhaps that's the only way to go then, can't be done with pure css then?

Comment: i've added masonry and tried a couple of things but it seems quite inconsistent, sometimes the layout breaks as you resize the browser, it's also hard to give consistent margins to the panels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I'd share my solution for this, since masonry was a bit overkill for this and didn't work as cleanly as I would've liked.

I have two classes in my css left-widget and right-widget, these are then set their widths and floats using a grid system, which essentially gives them float left and float right and 49.something% width.

By default I give all the widgets the left-widget class, and then with some jquery I do this:

```
$('.left-widget').each(function (index, value) {
                var widgetPosition = $(this).position().left;
                if (widgetPosition >= 30) {
                    $(this).removeClass('left-widget').addClass('right-widget');
                }
            });
            $('.right-widget').each(function (index, value) {
                var widgetPosition = $(this).position().left;
                if (widgetPosition <= 30) {
                    $(this).removeClass('right-widget').addClass('left-widget');
                }
            });
```

This now does exactly what I wanted it to do, sticking the widgets to the right if they fit.

Answer (score -1):

Use CSS media queries:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
   #box-js {display:none}
}
```

The CSS rule for `#box-js` will only be executed when the screen with is below 1000px.

Comment: sorry am i missing something? where's box-js in this? have you got the wrong question?